# Flattening a very ragged tensor in TF 2.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, reshape

I have finally migrated to TF 2.1, and I am trying to port my code to native TF 2.1. So here's a question: how does one go about reshaping a ragged tensor of various ranks into a 1-dimensional tensor? Essentially, I have a set of weight matrices, eg. `[3,3,1,32], [32], [21632,20], [20], [20,10], [10]` (these are shapes, not values), and I want to flatten this entire monstrosity into a 1-d tensor. What's the most efficient way of doing this? Better still, how do I go about writing a function to flatten a tensor of arbitrary length of any level of shape raggedness?

Currently, I am using the following solution, but I suspect that Python list might slow everything down tremendously:

```
gradlist = []
for g in gradients:
    gradlist.append(tf.reshape(g, [-1]))
grad_vector = tf.concat(gradlist, 0)
```

Comment: I think this is the canonical way of doing it. Why do you suspect this is slow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy `hstack` to flatten the numpy array easily, this should be faster.

ref: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html

Code example:

```
import numpy as np

gradients = np.array([[1], [1,2,3], [4,5]])

print(np.hstack(gradients).shape)

print(np.hstack(gradients))
```

Out:

```
(6,)
[1 1 2 3 4 5]
```

Comment: I assumed that numpy does not run on GPU. Is this assumption wrong? I was explicitly trying to avoid using any numpy references, and use exclusively tf functions to enable optimal hardware acceleration.

Comment: But how you're keeping your uneven arrays? You can't be using tensor, so that's why I used numpy. You can use numpy inside tf, look at this: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function